# SQL (nette) returning weird number of rows

Tags: sql, limit, nette

I have a query in PHP framework nette...
it looks like this

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table")->fetchAll(); //count($result) = 20874;
```

But then I do this for testing purposes:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = '123'")->fetchAll(); //count($result) = 12;
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE value <> '123'")->fetchAll(); //count($result) = 20874;
```

The problem is, when I iterate through $result from first classic query like this

```
foreach($result as $r){
    if($value == "123"){
         print_r("I FOUND HIM");die();
    }
}
```

It never "finds him". I mean the rows are obviously there, but aren't in query results without condition. Is it possible, that there is any limit? Thanks

Comment: What is the datatype of column `value`?

Comment: It is varchar(20)

Comment: These results make no sense. If you have `20874` rows total, how can `WHERE value <> '123'` return the same number of rows, while `WHERE value = '123'` returns `12` rows?

Comment: You could inspect the results of the `WHERE value = '123'` query and see what they contain.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I am getting confused. Tried whole query in phpmyadmin, same nubmers.

Comment: Rows are the same... It looks like that WHEN I DONT SPECIFY value='123'  it doesn't iclude rows in result. But I do not know why